# Why is my mathematical equation producing an incorrect result?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a scale amount in my game, and occasionally the mathematical equation will produce an incorrect answer for the amountToScale variable. Here are the answers that my code is returning, and as you can see, 686 / newDownObject.size.width which is 505 does not equal 1.579. Why is this happening? Any help is appreciated!

Here are the answers my code is producing:

height : 545.0

width: 505.0

scale: 1.57981651376147

new height : 861.0

new width: 797.807339449541

```
if newDownObject.size.width >= newDownObject.size.height {

        let amountToScale = 686 / newDownObject.size.width

        let scale = SKAction.scale(by: amountToScale, duration: 0.25)

        newDownObject.run(scale)

        let newHeight = newDownObject.size.height * amountToScale
        let newWidth = newDownObject.size.width * amountToScale

        let scaleBackground = SKAction.resize(toWidth: newWidth + 14, height: newHeight + 14, duration: 0.25)

        newDownObjectBackground.run(scaleBackground)

        print("height : \(newDownObject.size.height)")
        print("width: \(newDownObject.size.width)")
        print("scale: \(amountToScale)")
        print("new height : \(newHeight)")
        print("new width: \(newWidth)")

    }
```

Comment: It is producing scale: 1.57981651376147 if you want to keep 2 places or 3 places after decimal just do that right

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was it’s just producing a completely incorrect answer. It should be producing roughly 1.3 but I can’t figure out why it’s producing 1.5

Comment: I guess your other if construct is working coz you have no mentioned the height and I think newdownobject height is greater and you are not inside this if you have got other if right

Comment: Thank you so much I see the issue now! I had just overlooked that the screen width wasn’t as big as the screen height so when resizing the square, it would sometimes be to big.